# xss when http is added in the payload

Tags: web-application, xss

If a field is not santized(except <,>) and all it does is add http in payload and reflects the output, is it possible to execute script in the client side?

This is what output looks like for input ../javascript:alert(1)

```
<a href  = "http://../javascript:alert(1)" target ="_blank">
```

**Another Sample input :** 
Input :     "><>:

Output :

```
<a href = "http://"&gt;&lt;:" target="_blank">
```

Edit: It would be nice if someone can think of payload with javascript: ,atrribute like a way to prompt using javascript:prompt(1).

Comment: All the http code is doing is completing the link source. You would have to trigger the link.

Comment: Any example you can come up with ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `<` and `>` are encoded, ending the anchor tag and adding a new tag won't work. However, if `"` quotation marks aren't encoded or filtered out, you can definitely still get XSS. For example, `example.com/"+onclick="alert('XSS!')` as a URL input will generate the output `<a href="http://example.com/" onclick="alert('XSS!')" target="_blank">`.

The `onclick` alert is the easiest way (**EDIT:** as @pineappleman points out), but you could also add other events (such as `onmouseover`) and could display your own content in front of the page using CSS, which could allow an attacker to influence victims into doing things that they would not want to do (think clickjacking, but on the vulnerable page directly instead of via an iframe of that page).

Comment: The quote is not encoded. However the entire thing is still considered a URL.
For eg. for    
<a href="http://example.com/"onclick="alert('XSS!')">    and If I click, I get redirected to this URl => http://example.com/"onclick="alert('XSS!').

Comment: Did you miss the `+` (you could also do it with `%20` in the URL) to create a space between the `href` and the `onclick` event handler? Of the `href` attribute value is quoted, as it ought to be, then that attack should work.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not sanitized, but only "http" is added, than the app it's vulnerable to XSS. For example, if the data is inserted in a href attribute like this:

```
<a href="http://userdata">
```

then an attacker could instead of **userdata** enter `"><img src=x onerror=alert()` what would result in:

```
<a href="http://"><img src=x onerror=alert()">
```

**Edit:** In the second example you added, the < and > signs are encoded. You could try to insert `" onclick="alert()` what could execute a script when somebody clicks on the link.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the confusion. Please read the question again. :)

Comment: I added some info :)

Comment: The edit says that quote is not filtered. Only > and < is filtered.

Comment: Thanks again, the output is :
  

<a href='http://"onclick = alert(1)'   . Quote is not encoded, but the entire thing is considered a URL.

Comment: try inserting a single quote (') instead of double qoute